# Problema com Ajax não suporta BLOB ?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Quero trazer uma arquivo com ajax que esta no meu banco de dados só que o arquivo se tornar grande demais para o ajax. Tem como modifica o ajax para ele traz o arquivo ou existe outra forma.

MEU CÓDIGO AJAX

```
$('#datatable-responsive tbody td').click(function(){
              alert($(this).eq(0).text());
              $('#myModal').modal();

            $.ajax({

                url: 'php/ajax/arquivo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                          metodo:     'MontarArquivo',
                          idARQUIVO:        $(this).eq(0).text()
                        },
                cache: false,
                datatype: "json",
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    var msg = '';
                      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                          msg = 'Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor.\n Verifique a rede.';
                      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                          msg = 'Página solicitada não encontrada. [404]';
                      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                          msg = 'Erro interno do servidor [500].';
                      } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                          msg = 'A análise JSON solicitada falhou.';
                      } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                          msg = 'Erro de tempo limite.';
                      } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                          msg = 'Pedido Ajax abortado.';
                      } else {
                          msg = 'Erro não detectado.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                      }
                      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                      messageError(msg,'danger', 'Error:');

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.containerArquivo').html(data);
                },
            });

        });
```

Comment: Qual foi o erro obtido no AJAX?